# JavaScript setTimeout loop doesn't break or appears to be holding it's own copy of global variable?

Tags: javascript

I've spent past 5 hours debugging, testing and trying to figure out what's wrong and I simply have no more options.

It seems my setTimeout loop keeps it's own copy of global variable.

Here is a function:

```
function playLights(){
    if(bombPlanted == true){
        console.log("bombPlanted: "+bombPlanted);

        if(elapsed < repeats){
            setTimeout(playLights, 1000);
        }
        else{
            bombPlanted = false;
        }
    elapsed++;
    }
}
```

These are variables and a function that resets them:

```
var repeats = 40;
var elapsed = 0;
var bombPlanted = false;

function initVars(){
    repeats = 40;
    elapsed = 0;
    bombPlanted = true;
}
```

and this is where action is started:

```
    if(roundInfo.added.round.bomb){
        initVars();
        playLights();
    }
```

This is where it's supposed to set bombPlanted to false and what I assume - break the setTimeout loop:

```
    if(roundInfo.round.phase == "freezetime"){
        bombPlanted = false;
        console.log("setting bomb to false");
    }
```

This is output from Node.js:

```
bombPlanted: true
bombPlanted: true
bombPlanted: true
bombPlanted: true
bombPlanted: true
bombPlanted: true
bombPlanted: true
bombPlanted: true
bombPlanted: true
bombPlanted: true
Handling POST request... [This is where new round starts]
setting bomb to false
bombPlanted: true
bombPlanted: true
bombPlanted: true
bombPlanted: true
bombPlanted: true
```

When bomb plant fully completes and it explodes - everything is reset fine but if the bomb plant fails to explode due to round ending faster - it will keep ticking and launching setTimeout.

As you can see: during freezetime phase - it gets called and does indeed set bombPlanted to false but the old loop keeps ticking.

Does my loop keep it's own copy of bombPlanted variable and refuses to update it until all script is finished?

Edit:
I just realized it's most likely related to responses.

```
if(roundInfo.added.round.bomb){
   initVars();
   playLights();
}
```

and

```
if(roundInfo.round.phase == "freezetime"){
   bombPlanted = false;
   console.log("setting bomb to false");
}
```

is wrapped in:

```
if (req.method == 'POST') {
        console.log("Handling POST request...");
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
```

**[HERE]**

```
        res.end( '' );
        });
}
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and provide a *runnable* example.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't think I can do that, this is basically just a script that takes data from Counter Strike Global Offensive game - and based on that data - performs actions (in my case adjusts color of my Light bulbs)

Comment: How does that keep you from providing a MCVE?

Comment: @melpomene oh I get it now, okay will make edits now. Thank you.

Comment: @melpomene - is this better?

Comment: Since you mentioned **Counter Strike**.. I will give all my possible help :)

Comment: Can you try using a `setInterval` in your `playLights` function and see... Right now the code seems to be fine..

Comment: @RajshekarReddy the problem with setInterval I had was - I could not dynamically adjust interval time without having to cancel current setInterval iteration, so I went with setTimeout.

Comment: Oh ok.. do you think you can reproduce the issue in a JSfiddle or something

Comment: @RajshekarReddy tried it https://jsfiddle.net/t5enzhry/
Not reproducible in JSFiddle.

Comment: Hmmm.. check if the scope of the variable is same in both cases in your code. I believe the one in `freezetime` is playing with a different scoped variable

Comment: What does the code for this "Handling POST request..." do? Likely a scope problem.

Comment: @K3N I just edited question.

Comment: Is the code spread across different modules (main or required)? Module code,meaning the main module and any others included with `require`, are compiled in their own function scope below global scope. They do not share variables between themselves and using multiple modules may produce similar symptoms. See also http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? or still no luck?

Comment: @AleRemote225 Not really. You keep posting descriptions of what you think your code does, not your code. But what you think your code does is not what it actually does, otherwise you wouldn't be here asking for help. We can't solve this without seeing actual code.

Comment: @melpomene I understood it now, it was my mistake by not providing whole code.

Comment: @melpomene Turns out the server = http.createServer( function(req, res) { was important part even though I thought it's not relevant. 

I will make sure to post full page of code next time with all parts. Sorry.